# How to add cron jobs dynamically by reading from file, irrespective of server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I want to add cron job dynamically once user install a php application on their server, like admin configuration, I need to set cron job dynamically once going thought its configuration settings in php?
I am using codeigniter to set the cron job, also I added the same from cpanel manually and it is working fine.

Comment: WHat happend if I install the PHP on a windows PC? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the replies, I got my answer now, based on the replies
I tried to add a new cronjob to crontab file using php (codeigniter):
following is my answer

```
$phppath =  exec('which php');
$user_file_path =  getcwd();
$cronjob1 = "0 0 1 * * $phppath  $user_file_path/index.php 
automatic_updates/leave_update_cron";
// run each cron job
// get all current cron jobs
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
// add our new job
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.$cronjob1.PHP_EOL);
// once append the job, execute the new file
exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

This will add a new cronjob without deleting anything on the current cronjob file

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file in

> /etc/cron.d

and use PHP's `file_put_contents()` to update the file. However, you'll need to elevate PHP or Apache's permissions (depending on your PHP handler). This isn't recommended since it leads to security issues.

If you're using Cron to run PHP scripts, then you can call the scripts directly using PHP every X amount of time. Create a variable in your database representing the last time your script was run. If X amount of time passed since the script was run, then you run the script and update the variable.
If the script takes a long time to execute, then use PHP to run it in a separate process, so the user doesn't have to wait for it to finish.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply... 1st solution : since it is not recommended , i am not preffering it, in second method,is it effect execution time, so i have to check this function everytime right ? it will be execute only if that application run atleast once a day right ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using shell script

```
shell_exec('echo "25 15 * * * <path to php> /var/www/cronjob/helloworld.php > /var/www/cronjob/cron.log" | crontab -')
```

you can use these functions or class

```
class Crontab {

     // In this class, array instead of string would be the standard input /  output format.

      // Legacy way to add a job:
  // $output = shell_exec('(crontab -l; echo "'.$job.'") | crontab -');

static private function stringToArray($jobs = '') {
$array = explode("\r\n", trim($jobs)); // trim() gets rid of the last \r\n
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if ($item == '') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
return $array;
}

static private function arrayToString($jobs = array()) {
    $string = implode("\r\n", $jobs);
    return $string;
 }

static public function getJobs() {
   $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');

   return self::stringToArray($output);
 }

static public function saveJobs($jobs = array()) {
    $output = shell_exec('echo "'.self::arrayToString($jobs).'" | crontab -');
    return $output; 
}

static public function doesJobExist($job = '') {
    $jobs = self::getJobs();
   if (in_array($job, $jobs)) {
       return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }

 static public function addJob($job = '') {
    if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
        return false;
   } else {
       $jobs = self::getJobs();
       $jobs[] = $job;
       return self::saveJobs($jobs);
    }
 }

  static public function removeJob($job = '') {
      if (self::doesJobExist($job)) {
          $jobs = self::getJobs();
          unset($jobs[array_search($job, $jobs)]);
          return self::saveJobs($jobs);
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it helped a lot, but i want to append to that file, not overwrite, any method for that?

Comment: then you need to use crontab -e which edit the crontab file

Comment: i want to avoid user intervention to edit this crontab. Need to make all this automate and also need to ensure the  existing contents of crontab file (/var/spool/cron/<username>) won't get lost

Comment: yes this will work for you with the above mentioned class. I have achieved the same

Answer (score 0):

First You have to create one txt file for example crontab.txt
then you have to use shell script like below

```
exec ( 'sudo crontab -u apache -r' );
file_put_contents ( '/var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT/crontab.txt',"25 15 * * * php /var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_CONTROLLER/YOUR_METHOD'.PHP_EOL);
```

And Lastly, you have to execute that file like

```
exec ( 'crontab /var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT/crontab.txt' );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i want to append to that file, not overwrite, any method for that?

Comment: For File Append you can use `FILE_APPEND` like below

`file_put_contents ( '/var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT/crontab.txt',"25 15 * * * php /var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_CONTROLLER/YOUR_METHOD'.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);`